# How can I make Spacemacs stop deleting my parentheses?

Tags: spacemacs, balanced-parentheses, smartparens

I've recently switched from emacs to spacemacs (develop branch), and I'm still getting used to the new defaults. I added `smartparens` to my `excluded-packages` in my config file, because I don't like parenthesis matching. Ususally, I open and close parentheses myself, and then `C-b` to move between the parens and type. But once I turned off `smartparens`, if I move between parens that I opened and closed, it will sometimes delete the close paren that I typed. In particular, this happens when I am in a function or for loop, or something else with a close curly brace. I'll type `someFunctionCall()` within a `for{}`, and as I'm filling in the arguments to the function call, the `)` will disappear and the `}` will turn red, like it's upset that I'm trying to close the `(` with the wrong bracket type. How do I stop this behavior? I've attached my `.spacemacs` as a gist for reference. I've seen this happen in ESS and C-mode so I don't think it's mode specific.

https://gist.github.com/esander91/d9fad132988965b6d015

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, perhaps this is a Spacemacs design problem (too closely integrated with smartparens?). Consider asking the Spacemacs maintainer.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, even with your `.spacemacs`. Try using the "Getting Help" section on the Spacemacs Github: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs#getting-help

Comment: Yeah, I think there's something funny going on, because I added smartparens back in but now I'm still having the issue. At this point it's even difficult to identify what the source of the behavior is.